# Animate ImageView using translation and rotation

Tags: java, android

I made my own way to animate the ImageView, but I'm pretty sure that there's a better approach that is short and won't cause a memory leak when the activity is destroyed.

The code that animates the image:

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        floatImage(true, imageView);
    }

private void floatImage(boolean isRotating, View view) {
        if (isRotating) {
            shadAnim(view, "rotation", 5, 4000);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                shadAnim(view, "rotation", -5, 4000);
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> floatImage(true, view), 4000);
            }, 3500);
        } else {
            shadAnim(view, "translationY", -50, 3000);
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                shadAnim(view, "translationY", 0, 3000);
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> floatImage(false, view), 3000);
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

 private void shadAnim(View view, String propertyName, double value, int duration) {
        ObjectAnimator anim = new ObjectAnimator();
        anim.setTarget(view);
        anim.setPropertyName(propertyName);
        anim.setFloatValues((float) value);
        anim.setDuration(duration);
        anim.start();
    }
```

This way works as intended but I'm asking if there's a better way to do it. Moreover, won't cause this memory leak:

```
┬───
    │ GC Root: System class
    │
    ├─ android.app.ActivityThread class
    │    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue↓ is not leaking and a class is never leaking)
    │    ↓ static ActivityThread.sMainThreadHandler
    ├─ android.app.ActivityThread$H instance
    │    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue↓ is not leaking)
    │    ↓ Handler.mQueue
    ├─ android.os.MessageQueue instance
    │    Leaking: NO (MessageQueue#mQuitting is false)
    │    HandlerThread: "main"
    │    ↓ MessageQueue[0]
    │                  ~~~
    ├─ android.os.Message instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 101 B in 3 objects
    │    Message.what = 0
    │    Message.when = 571932311 (1090 ms after heap dump)
    │    Message.obj = null
    │    Message.callback = instance @317197168 of com.project.app.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4
    │    Message.target = instance @315951112 of android.os.Handler
    │    ↓ Message.callback
    │              ~~~~~~~~
    ├─ com.project.app.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4 instance
    │    Leaking: UNKNOWN
    │    Retaining 12 B in 1 objects
    │    f$0 instance of com.project.app.MainActivity with mDestroyed = true
    │    ↓ SettingsActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.f$0
    │                                                 ~~~
    ╰→ com.project.app.MainActivity instance
    ​     Leaking: YES (ObjectWatcher was watching this because com.project.app.MainActivity received
    ​     Activity#onDestroy() callback and Activity#mDestroyed is true)
    ​     Retaining 1.2 MB in 3534 objects
    ​     key = 701a92c3-d630-4d18-89a4-47b9e79b8734
    ​     watchDurationMillis = 8268
    ​     retainedDurationMillis = 3263
    ​     mApplication instance of android.app.Application
    ​     mBase instance of androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper
```

Comment: Looks like you are call the floatImage() recursively and it creates new object on each call.
The better option would be to define your animation in xml and parse it using AnimationUtils library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better option would be to

1. define your animation in xml.
2. Load it using AnimationUtils library.
3. Attach the animation to the view.

Step 1:
Create a new animation resource file. (res/anim/mySuperAnimation.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    <-- Fine tune the parameters according to your needs -->
    android:duration="300" 
    android:fromYDelta="5" 
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toYDelta="-5" />
</set>
```

Step 2: Load the created mySuperAnimation.xml file to your animator object.

```
Animation mAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.mySuperAnimation);
```

Step 3: Link the animation to the view.

```
ImageView view = find(...);
view.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

To stop the animation you have to call clearAnimation() on the animating view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code but the image is not animating.

Comment: Can you share the modified code?

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. It works fine now.